# Cancel several async operations

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, alamofire

In my app's data update method, I perform several server requests handled by Alamofire. Some of data returned by server is being parsed and saved into core data, some is saved as image files or zip archives.

Requests are performed asynchronously. I wonder how to implement Cancel method which stops my updating requests. I doubt that I can wrap everything into NSOperationQueue as NSOperation wrapping each Alamofire.request will be completed immediately and long before Alamofire.request method is finished.

As I remember Alamofire has request cancellation method, but what happens if request is completed and user taps Cancel button while Alamofire.response completion handler is being executed (parsing data, rendering downloaded images, etc)

Comment: For my own needs I use state variables, things like, isUpdateInProgress, combined with NSTimers for things that need to be polled (and be invalidated when needed) and weak references to objects in closures to avoid crashes. I think the mindset for me is that the method can't be canceled but the unwanted response can be handled.

Comment: @thefredelement Well, I do track the loading progress using OptionalSetType, fulfilling an array of states with recently finished state. But the problem appears when user decides that loading process takes too long and he don't want to wait anymore. Or his internet connection was interrupted (i.e. if in this case I'm downloading an image, then I don't get any responses from Alamofire, even in 100 secs which is my currently set timeoutConnectionRequest interval. However in the same situation apps like Facebook or Pandora respond immediately)

Comment: You can respond to events through the app delegate that effect the state of your app, and when doing so, you can check on things. It's vague to say I know but just think about one example and what you want to happen depending on the state of the app and you'll see what I mean, I hope.